# Cartan subalgebras and Jordan Normal form

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm stuck with Kac notes on Introduction to Lie Algebras. I logically understand all the definitions and everything is fine but I can't understand what's the thinking behind it. So **I'm not asking** for a rigorous proof o explanation, while I'd like **a picture** of what's happening behind the scenes.

We have for semi-simple Lie Algebra that the algebra is decomposable in: 
$$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus(\bigoplus_{\alpha \in \mathfrak{h}^*} \mathfrak{g}_\alpha)$$
Where $\mathfrak{h}$ is the Cartan subAlgebra, the $\alpha$ are the roots, etc...

I'd like to know:

1. what's going on. Please pick the most useful point of view let you understand the picture (doesn't matter if it's geometric, algebric, heuristic, etc...)
2. what is the relation if any with the Jordan Normal Form? (In plain english if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weight spaces" $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ are like the "generalized eigenspaces", which correspond to the blocks of a Jordan matrix. More specifically, for an element $x \in \mathfrak{h}$, it's acting on the whole space $\mathfrak{g}$ via the adjoint representation ($\mathrm{ad}_x(y) = [x,y]$). So you can think of $x$ (or $\mathrm{ad}_x$) as a matrix, after picking a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$. If $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $x$, then when you write $x$ in Jordan canonical form, it is block diagonal, and one of the blocks will look like:
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cccc} \alpha & 1 & & \\ 
 & \alpha & \ddots & \\
 & & \ddots & 1 \\
 & & & \alpha \end{array} \right) $$

The invariant subspace corresponding to this block of the matrix is the $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$, the "generalized eigenspace". Notice the connection to the property which defines the $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$: if $v \in \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$, there is some $k$ so that $(x - \alpha \, \mathrm{Id}_\mathfrak{g})^k v = 0$. Here $k$ is the size of the block corresponding to $\alpha$, and the matrix above certainly satisfies $(x - \alpha \, \mathrm{Id})^k = 0$.

Comment: this was really helpful! Thanks!